# Grails 2.3.1 returns 404 after changing controller

Tags: grails

After any change in a controller, its actions start to returns 404. This is true to all actions in the modified controller.
The only way to solve it is to perform:

```
grails clean
```

and then launch the app again by: `grails run-app`.
Once that is done, all is good again.

Needless to say that this is not the most desired situation.

Any ideas ?

Thank you in advance
Eduardo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade? There have been 11 patch releases since 2.3.0, and upgrading within a minor version (2.3.x) is typically very simple - just update `application.properties` and any plugins that are listed as working with particular version of Grails (e.g. Tomcat, Hibernate).

Even better - create a new empty 2.3.11 app and a new empty 2.3.1 app. Do a directory diff (ignoring `target`) - http://meldmerge.org/ is a great option for this since it's open source and cross-platform - and that will tell you exactly what changed between the versions. Make the changes necessary to update your 2.3.1 app to 2.3.11 and you should be good to go. Alternately you could diff your app with the empty 2.3.1 app, which would tell you what you deleted, changed, and added, and you can make those same changes in the empty 2.3.11 app and then make that the real app. In either case the work shouldn't be significant - this 3-way diff approach is a generic one that works very well when you're upgrading to higher minor or major versions.

Comment: +1 just for the upgrade process... that's a good idea.  I miss grails update ... well, since it rarely worked, maybe I don't.

Comment: Yep, it was misleading because it implied that it was doing more than updating the .tld and .xml files in WEB-INF and changing the version in application.properties. Programmatically updating would be possible, but a lot of work and still error-prone and requiring human intervention

Comment: Thank you, upgrading to 2.3.11 solves the partial compilation issue.
Now I can actually change controllers without the need to clean, restart ;-)